# can not find -lwebsock

Tags: video-streaming

I am installing janus gateway to implement webrtc in ubuntu 14.04.
I have installed all the dependencies according to the [documentation](http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/), when I run the script using `sh install.sh`  I get the following error:

```
gcc -fstack-protector-all -g -ggdb -rdynamic  -o test test.o -lwebsock
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebsock
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gayan/MyDetails/MyApplications/virtualClassRoomTest/janus-gateway/wstest'
make: *** [wstest] Error 2

The installer couldn't find the libwebsock lib, which is needed for WebSockets
You can install version 1.0.4 (required!) with the following steps:
    wget http://paydensutherland.com/libwebsock-1.0.4.tar.gz
    tar xfv libwebsock-1.0.4.tar.gz
    cd libwebsock-1.0.4
    ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install

    [Note: you may need to pass --libdir=/usr/lib64 to the configure script if you're installing on a x86_64 distribution]
```

I have also install the libwebsock using above steps. Any kind of help is appreciated.

[https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have not installed libwebsock library properly. Try following link to install libwebsock library . https://github.com/payden/libwebsock/wiki/Installation

After installation check whether the shared library libwebsock.so is availabale. If so you successfully installed the libwebsock library